# Hyperledger Fabric - Computing data_hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, hyperledger-fabric

The query system chaincode function "GetBlockByNumber" returns a protobuf-encoded block. I know that it can be decoded to a message like this:

```
block = {
  "header": {
    "number": "5",
    "previous_hash": "7wkVw+hT/akRY5Y32NII0mWTLqwHv8Qp9FRAlhd+HTc=",
    "data_hash": "OnTlaDYd5PDtNPj3W0SADb6wRFQ8U7Nq4yctDfdMcnM="
  },
  "data": // block data,
  "metadata": // block metadata,
}
```

How do you compute `block.header.data_hash` using `block.data`?
I have tried using protobuf tools like protobufjs to extract `block.data` and apply sha256 to it, but the result is not consistent with the data_hash.

```
const {Type, Field} = require('protobufjs');
const {createHash} = require('crypto');
const blockRaw = 'some_protobuf_encoded_string';
const protoBlockHeader = new Type('BlockHeader')
  .add(new Field('number', 1, 'uint64'))
  .add(new Field('previous_hash', 2, 'bytes'))
  .add(new Field('data_hash', 3, 'bytes'));
const protoBlock = new Type('Block')
  .add(new Field('block_header', 1, 'BlockHeader')).add(protoBlockHeader)
  .add(new Field('block_data', 2, 'bytes'));
const block = protoBlock.decode(blockRaw);
const hash = createHash('sha256');
hash.update(block.block_data);
const computed = hash.digest();
const expected = block.header.data_hash;
console.log(computed.compare(expected) === 0); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the data element bytes together and then take sha256 hash. Here is the [Fabric Go code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/protoutil/blockutils.go#L65-L68) that does it.

Comment: I read the source code too, but didn't work on first try. I finally got it working. If you are to include some sample codes for people reading this question in the future I'm happy to accept your answer.